# Replacing an object on so that all references to it are kept

Tags: c#, ref

I wanted to understand more about how the ref keyword works so I made the following experiment:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var main = new Main { Property = 1 };
        var dependent = new Dependent(main);

        void ChangeRef(ref Main Oldmain, Main newMain)
        {
            Oldmain = newMain;

        }

        ChangeRef(ref main, new Main { Property = 5 });

        Assert.AreEqual(5,dependent.Main.Property);
    }
}

public class Main
{
    public int Property { get; set; }
}

public class Dependent
{
    public Dependent(Main main)
    {
        Main = main;
    }

    public Main Main { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see I was expecting to be able to replace the object that main was referencing while keeping the reference, but the test fails and with the value still being 1.  Could someone elaborate abit on why that wasnt working or point me to a place where I can read more?

Update:
Like someone answered below, but later removed.
Why doesnt it work if I pass the main object by reference to the dependent in the constructor? 
Shouldnt they all have the same reference?

Comment: You created a `Main`. You created a `Dependent` with a reference to that `Main`. Then you create a completely new `Main`. `dependent` can't see that `Main`. `dependent` doesn't have a reference to the `main` **variable** - it has a reference to the **object** that the `main` **variable** pointed to at that point in time. If you point the `main` **variable** to a different object (like you did here), `dependent` doesn't magically know about it. _Now if `ChangeRef` didn't **assign** to `Oldmain` but inside changed its properties then everything would work as you expect._

Comment: Because all are reference types. You create main to point to memory location #1, then you created dependent.Main pointing to the same memory location #1. Then you created new Main { Property = 5} which pointing to memory location #2 and then assign main to pointing to #2. But dependent.Main still pointing to #1.

Comment: Ok, but is there any way that I can replace the object that dependent objects are pointing at without just changing all their properties?

Comment: `Ok, but is there any way that I can replace the object that dependent objects are pointing at without just changing all their properties?` No.

Comment: @mjwills No, it won't work. I have something else in mind, because I am trying to explain pointing to the memory it might be confusing...Thanks for pointing.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed, you cannot instantly make all variables and fields in your program point to a different instance.

But if you want to reflect a change in all parts of the program, the simplest way is to wrap it in a different class (like your `Dependent` class). Then you can share the class with other parts of the program, and change its properties instead:

```
class SomeOtherObject
{
    readonly Dependent _dependent;
    public Dependent { get { return _dependent; }}

    public SomeOtherObject(Dependent dependent)
    {
        _dependent = dependent;
    }

    public void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_dependent.Main.Property);
    }
}
```

So now you can do this:

```
var dependent = new Dependent(new Main { Property = 1 });
var someOtherObject = new SomeOtherObject(dependent);

// this will print "1"
someOtherObject.Print();

dependent.Main = new Main { Property = 5; };

// this will print "5"
someOtherObject.Print();
```

In this case, obviously, simply changing `dependent.Main.Property` would also do the trick. So, if all parts of your program point to a single object, you can mutate it (i.e. change its internal data) and everyone will see the change, but you cannot make all parts of your program change what they are pointing to.

It's worth noting that you need to be careful when doing this in multithreaded programs; you rarely want some other thread to be able to randomly change your internal data.

That's also why it's best to try to keep your properties readonly, and your objects immutable, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

After doing that

```
var main = new Main { Property = 1 };
```

You have object of type `Main` allocated somewhere in memory (let's name it `Main1`), at some memory address X, and variable `main` points to that object. "Points" means it literally stores address of that object `Main1`, so `main` contains `X`.

Then you pass reference to `Main1` to the constructor of `Dependent` object

```
var dependent = new Dependent(main);
```

`Dependent` object is also allocated somewhere in memory, and one of its fields stores reference to `Main1` object. So `dependent.Main` also stores X.

When you do

```
ChangeRef(ref main, new Main { Property = 5 });
```

You allocate new object `Main5` somewhere at memory address `Y`. Now you change what address variable `main` points to. Before it stored address `X` (address of `Main1`), now it stores address `Y` (address of `Main5`). But `dependent.Main` still stores address `X`, because you didn't change it in any way, so it still points to object `Main1`.

Comment: Ok, but I want to replace main1, not the reference, but the actual object so that all the references that points to that object points to my new object. Is that possible?

Comment: @Erik83 nope, that's not generally possible.

Comment: ok. Good to know so I can stop chasing that... =)
But doesnt that seem odd? Or is there a security reason for that?

Comment: @Erik83 well doesn't seem odd for me, never needed to do that in practice. In your example you can just set `main.Property = 5` and this change will be reflected for everyone using this object. You don't need `ref` for that.

Comment: well, If you have a complex object with lots of nested objects or if just simply cant change the properties. I just thought is was wierd that it wasnt possible to write directly to that location in memory...

Comment: @Erik83 well that is managed language, not C. It's just not designed for direct working with memory in that way. Garbage collector for example is free to move objects in memory as it wants to, and it can do that right in the middle of you overwriting object memory.